# Numbering cleardoublepage

Tags: page-numbering, book-design

When I'm using `\cleardoublepage` in the `twoside` `book` to have a sort of `oneside` book, with the content in the odd page and a blank page in the other side (even page) but looking at the footer of the next page (the one with the other content) I get the previous page number + 2. For example if the first content is at page 123, then `\cleardoublepage` the next content is at page 125. How can I avoid that Latex counts also blank pages here?

This thing it is done every time that there is a blank page, even for the chapters that by default add a new chapter in the odd page with a page number that is +2 the page number with contents.

I don't think that I need to add codes or examples. The layout is always the same:

```
page with content -> blank page -> page with content
page number     -> no page number -> page number +2
```

Comment: Isn't oneside what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope I need the twoside

Comment: Assuming I understand what you want, I would create a oneside document and convert it to twoside using pdfpages.  (Or just set the printer driver to print onesided.)